# Eloquent relationships: cloumn doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and am having a bit of a hard time cracking how relationships work. I'm building a simple e-commerce application, where each user has some orders, and order has one or many sub-orders, and each sub-order is linked to only one item (please don't comment on my scheme yet; for now I just need to figure out Eloquent and will be doing refactoring later :) ).

Following are my models:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    //timestamp
    protected $created_at;

    public function sub_orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubOrder');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}

class SubOrder extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('delivery_date', 'quantity', 'total_price', 'delivery_status');

    public function item() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Item');
    }

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    //note - slug is kind of categorization and is common to many items
    protected $fillable = array('sku', 'name', 'slug', 'unit_price');
}
```

And here are the migrations:

```
class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');

            //foreign keys
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->after('id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    }
}


class CreateSubOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sub_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('delivery_date');
            $table->decimal('quantity', 5, 2);
            $table->decimal('total_price', 7, 2);
            $table->enum('delivery_status', ['pending_from_farmer', 'ready_for_customer', 'out_for_delivery', 'delivered']);

            //foreign keys
            $table->unsignedInteger('order_id')->after('id');
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('item_id')->after('order_id');
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('sub_orders');
    }
}

class CreateItemsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('sku')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->decimal('unit_price', 5, 2);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('items');
    }
}
```

The problematic expression is why I write `App\Order::all()[0]->sub_orders[0]->item` in my `web.php` and get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column items.sub_order_id does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "items" where "items"."sub_order_id" = $1 and ...
^ (SQL: select * from "items" where "items"."sub_order_id" = 1 and "items"."sub_order_id" is not null limit 1)
```

I don't understand why it's looking for `sub_order_id` in the `items` table. And what's the right way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall: define the 1-to-1 relationship using `hasOne` or `belongsTo` will affect the target table where Laravel find the foreign key. `hasOne` assume there is a `my_model_id` in target table.And `belongsTo` assume there is a `target_model_id` in my table.

```
class SubOrder extends Model
{
  public function item() {
     return $this->hasOne('App\Item', 'id', 'item_id');
  }
}
```

or

```
class SubOrder extends Model
{
  public function item() {
     return $this-> belongsTo('App\Item');
  }
}
```

According to [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In the above case, **the Phone model** is automatically assumed to have a **user_id foreign key**. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method:

```
$this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Or Defining The Inverse Of The Relationship

```
class Phone extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

> In the example above, Eloquent will try to match the **user_id from the Phone** model to an **id on the User** model.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SubOrder` item has relationship of type `OneToOne` (`hasOne` is bidirectional) with an Item.
So `Eloquent` expects to have `sub_order_id` in the `items` table.

So the solution is to define the inverse of this relationship (`belongsTo`) in the `Item` model